# Java Design : Polymorphic List

Tags: java, data-structures, polymorphism, abstract

I have three classes A,B,C.

A is abstract, B and C extends A.

My goal is to give the user the ability to make List of C's or B's (not to have both in the same list), I want to enforce the user to do that by smart design.

My idea was to have abstract class AList with function:

```
void add (A a)
```

and two classes:

BList extending AList with function void add (B b) overriding AList's add.

CList extending AList with function void add (C c) overriding AList's add.

but that didn't work, since you can't change the function arguments (to be more specific) when overriding.

Comment: Do you mean *not* to have both in the same list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to enforce only a `List<B>` or a `List<C>`, then the way to do that is just to use factory methods:

```
class AList<T extends A> {
  private AList() {...} // users outside the class can't invoke the constructor

  public static AList<B> createBList() {
    return new AList<B>();
  }

  public static AList<C> createCList() {
    return new AList<C>();
  }
}
```

This forces users outside your class to use one of the factory methods, and the factory methods will only create lists of `B`s or `C`s, not `A`s.

That said, it's not clear what you're really trying to do.  There's nothing you can do to stop someone from creating an `ArrayList<A>` and putting both `B`s and `C`s in it, and it's also not clear why you want to reinvent the wheel and create your own list type.

Comment: Dont you need the generic after static?

Comment: @YassinHajaj No, that would defeat the point.  You actively _must not_ have the generic after static.  You don't want a new type variable, you want to refer to a specific named class.

Comment: Oh yes right thanks. The short names had me confuses.

Comment: @LouisWasserman thanks for the Idea, I'm writing an importer A,B,C encapsulate other classes the user needs to provide me with list of B's or C's, I can tell the user to give me List<A> but then I have to check manually (using instanceof for example) that he didn't mix B's and C's or I can use your Idea and ask the user to provide me with AList this way the user CANT make a mistake and mix them.

Answer (score 1):

Though I like @LouisWassermans solution, why don't you simply use generics to solve your issue?

```
public abstract class AList<T extends A>{

  public abstract void add(T a);

  ...

}

public class BList extends AList<B>{

  @Override
  public void add(B b){
    ...
  }
}

public class CList extends AList<C>{

  @Override
  public void add(C c){
    ...
  }
}
```